# How can I get the href attribute of *any* element in an XML (included deeply nested ones) using xpath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

[Python] I'm trying to retrieve any element in an XML document that has an `href` attribute, at any level of the XML document. For example:

```xml
<OuterElement href='a.com'>
  <InnerElement>
    <NestedInner href='b.com' />
    <NestedInner href='c.com' />
    <NestedInner />
  </InnerElement>
  <InnerElement href='d.com'/>
</OuterElement>
```

Would retrieve the following elements (as lxml element objects,simplified for visual clarity):

```py
[<OuterElement href='a.com'>, <NestedInner href='b.com' />, <NestedInner href='c.com' />, <InnerElement href='d.com'/>]
```

I've tried using the following code to retrieve any element with an href tag, but it retrieves zero elements on a file full of elements with href attributes:

```py
with(open(file, 'rb')) as f:
    xml_tree = etree.parse(f)
    href_elements = xml_tree.xpath(".//*[@href]")
```

Shouldn't this code select *any* element (`.//*`) with the specified attribute (`[@href]`)? From my understanding (definitely correct me if I am wrong, I most likely am), `href_elements` should be an array of lxml element objects that each have an href attribute.

**important clarification**: I have seen many people asking about xpath on Stack Overflow, but I have yet to find a solved question about how to search through *all* elements in an xml and retrieve every element that fits a criteria (such as href).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<OuterElement href='a.com'>
  <InnerElement>
    <NestedInner href='b.com' />
    <NestedInner href='c.com' />
    <NestedInner />
  </InnerElement>
  <InnerElement href='d.com'/>
</OuterElement>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
elements_with_href = [root] if 'href' in root.attrib else []
elements_with_href.extend(root.findall('.//*[@href]'))
for e in elements_with_href:
  print(f'{e.tag} : {e.attrib["href"]}')
```

output

```
OuterElement : a.com
NestedInner : b.com
NestedInner : c.com
InnerElement : d.com
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Can you link the documentation?

Comment: Just for anyone who comes through with this, I parse the XML tree from an xml file. So the line `root = ET.fromstring(xml)` gets replaced with `root = etree.parse(filename).getroot()`

Comment: @CameronGould, you can apply [`.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) as one-liner alternative: `[(e.tag, href) for e in root.iter() if (href := e.get("href"))]`